# Meaning of Icons in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

[image]

I am creating a new Login for IIS AppPool in SQL Server Management Studio 17. I have come across 2 types of icons for logins as mentioned by 1 and 2 in the image. What is the difference between these two types of users? Is there any differences in connection permission granting?

Comment: Where there is "one person" on the picture it's "normal", individual login, where you see "many persons" is a group (Windows group)

Comment: >>>Is there any differences in connection permission granting<<< When login is not **disabled** there is no red cross over it, otherwise you see redd x (row down in previuos versions)

Comment: How does the login type assigned to each new login created?

Comment: What do you mean by "type assigned"? If you create your login from individual win account, or create SQL Server login, it's individual. When you  create it from WINDOWS GROUP, it's win group login

Answer (score 1):

**Icon 1** = This indicates the Login is a **group**.

As example "BUILTIN\Administrators" is a group. This will allow all users that are part of Administrators group on the selected computer.

**Icon 2** = A **single user** Login.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reference for this somewhere?